# Draw 3D Fourier series with PGFPlot/TikZ

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I have a Fourier series given by

[image]

where `$k_n=\dfrac{n \pi}{a}$`.

I'd like to plot in 3D this Fourier series using PGFPlot or Ti*k*Z, but I have no idea how to do it. I just visited [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117330/draw-fourier-series-expansion-with-tikz-pgfplots) and [this other](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611594/graphing-fourier-series-with-tikz).

Thank you so much for any suggerstion or solution.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried. Just visiting links does not show any effort. You need to post some compilable code and ask about what is causing you problems.